# Running balance query in sql server 2005 with two column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want the output like below, i am having this four column, please help me to generate fifth column with sql query

```
31-Mar-13   Product-A   50000   0   50000
2-Apr-13    Product-A   0   2000    48000
4-Apr-13    Product-A   0   3000    45000
6-Apr-13    Product-A   0   2500    42500
9-Apr-13    Product-A   0   2500    40000
11-Apr-13   Product-A   0   3000    37000
15-Apr-13   Product-A   0   3000    34000
16-Apr-13   Product-A   0   2000    32000
18-Apr-13   Product-A   0   1000    31000
20-Apr-13   Product-A   0   2000    29000
```

my table having data like below, data might be changed.

```
   31-Mar-13    Product-A   50000   0
    2-Apr-13    Product-A   0   2000    
    4-Apr-13    Product-A   0   3000    
    6-Apr-13    Product-A   0   2500    
    9-Apr-13    Product-A   0   2500
    11-Apr-13   Product-A   0   3000    
    15-Apr-13   Product-A   0   3000    
    16-Apr-13   Product-A   0   2000    
    18-Apr-13   Product-A   0   1000    
    20-Apr-13   Product-A   0   2000
```

Comment: How about sharing your table structure, an explanation what you're trying to achieve, and what you've tried so far?

Comment: As you are a new user your are not allowed to upload images. Try to explain yourself by adding more information, show the code you have tried, table  structures,etc.

Comment: You can always post a link to your table image.

Comment: 1st structure what i want and 2nd structure i am having.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT '31-Mar-13' [Date],  'Product-A' product,  50000 val1 , 0 val2 , 50000 total into #temp union all SELECT 
 '2-Apr-13' ,  'Product-A' ,  0  , 2000  ,  48000 union all SELECT 
 '4-Apr-13' ,  'Product-A' ,  0  , 3000  ,  45000 union all SELECT 
 '6-Apr-13' ,  'Product-A' ,  0  , 2500  ,  42500 union all SELECT 
 '9-Apr-13' ,  'Product-A' ,  0  , 2500  ,  40000 union all SELECT 
 '11-Apr-13',  'Product-A' ,  0  , 3000  ,  37000 union all SELECT 
 '15-Apr-13',  'Product-A' ,  0  , 3000  ,  34000 union all SELECT 
 '16-Apr-13',  'Product-A' ,  0  , 2000  ,  32000 union all SELECT 
 '18-Apr-13',  'Product-A' ,  0  , 1000  ,  31000 union all SELECT 
 '20-Apr-13',  'Product-A' ,  0  , 2000  ,  29000

   select Date, product,    val1    ,val2 ,val1+val2 total from #temp
```

if val1, val2 are varchar/nvarchar then use

```
select Date,    product,    val1    ,val2 ,cast(val1 as int)+cast(val2 as int) total from #temp
```

Comment: i wnat to calculate running balance in fith column.

Answer (score 0):

check my query.my date col is datetime not varchar.also exclude the column you don't need.you basically need Mytotal from my sql.

```
Declare @t table([Date] date,product varchar(50),val1 int,val2 int,total int)
 insert into @t
 SELECT '03-31-13' [Date],  'Product-A' product,  50000 val1 , 0 val2 , 50000 total
 union all SELECT 
 '04-2-13' ,  'Product-A' ,  0  , 2000  ,  48000 union all SELECT 
 '04-4-13' ,  'Product-A' ,  0  , 3000  ,  45000 union all SELECT 
 '04-6-13' ,  'Product-A' ,  0  , 2500  ,  42500 union all SELECT 
 '04-9-13' ,  'Product-A' ,  0  , 2500  ,  40000 union all SELECT 
 '04-11-13',  'Product-A' ,  0  , 3000  ,  37000 union all SELECT 
 '04-15-13',  'Product-A' ,  0  , 3000  ,  34000 union all SELECT 
 '04-16-13',  'Product-A' ,  0  , 2000  ,  32000 union all SELECT 
 '04-18-13',  'Product-A' ,  0  , 1000  ,  31000 union all SELECT 
 '04-20-13',  'Product-A' ,  0  , 2000  ,  29000

--select *,row_number() over(order by date)rn  from @t a
;With CTE as
 (select *,row_number() over(order by date)rn from @t a
 )
 ,MAXCTE as
 (select max(rn) MaxRn from cte)
 ,CTE1 as
 (select *,val1-val2 as Mytotal from cte where rn=1
union all
select a.*,b.Mytotal-a.val2  from cte a 
inner join  cte1 b on a.product=b.product
cross apply MAXCTE mc
where a.rn between b.rn+1 and mc.MaxRn and a.rn-b.rn=1
 )

 select  a.*
from cte1 a
```